# Should I use `package:` import when importing my own package's library in Dart?

Tags: dart, import, package

I'm little bit confused about which style of import should I use when importing implementation libraries (code under `src/lib`) from another libraries (and tests) in my own package?

The docs recommends the opposite options.

In [`pub` docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout#implementation-files), it says:

> When you use libraries from within your own package, even code in src, you can (and should) still use `package:` to import them.

But in ["Effective Dart"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-relative-paths-when-importing-libraries-within-your-own-packages-lib-directory), it says:

> When referencing a library inside your package’s lib directory from another library in that same package, use a relative URI, not an explicit `package:` URI.

In the end, which style should I use in such cases:

- import implementation library (under `lib/src/`) from with public library (under just `lib/`)?
- import implementation library (`lib/src/foo.dart`) from within its test (`test/src(?)/foo_test.dart`)?
- import public library (`lib/foo.dart`) from within its test (`test/foo_test.dart`)?

Comment: You found what's clearly a bug in the documentation, so [filing a bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues) seems like the best course for clarifying the recommendation.

Comment: That said, if you look at the git history for those two parts of the documentation, you'll see that that part of the `pub` docs was written 4 years ago, whereas that part of Effective Dart was written 4 *months* ago, so the Effective Dart recommendation is more likely to be current.  In general, as a centralized source for recommendations, Effective Dart is more visible and is more likely to follow currently recommended practices.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2606

Comment: IMO, reading documentation shouldn't require user to mess around *git commits history* in order to just know that documentation is outdated. It should be marked directly in documentation itself using big red title: "This is outdated!"

Comment: I never claimed that looking at Git history is *required*; I'm just using that to provide supporting evidence.  The `pub` documentation isn't *supposed* to be outdated.  The documentation authors can't mark something with "This is outdated!" if they don't *already* know that it's outdated (and if they knew that, they could fix it or remove it instead). Accidental oversights happen, especially when there's a lot of documentation and when some things are documented in multiple places.  And if some things weren't documented in multiple places, then information would be harder to find.

Comment: If you see an error in the documentation, your best course of action is to file a bug to get it corrected.